# In c++ why we can overload `operator ->` and can't overload `operator .`

Tags: c++

In c++, why we can overload `operator ->` and can't overload `operator .`?
Similarly, why we can overload `operator ->*` and can't overload `operator .*`?
I will be appreciated if you can help me!

Comment: Have you read https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup?

Comment: Because the C++ standard specifies so.

Comment: Because it'd be utter madness if we could. Just look at all the nastiness `operator&` causes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sigh. Why does the standard specify so?

Comment: Because no one has made a coherent proposal for such feature. Try and see why it's hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stroustrup actually has this as an FAQ question on his [website](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot). To quote his answer:

> Operator . (dot) could in principle be overloaded using the same technique as used for ->. However, doing so can lead to questions about whether an operation is meant for the object overloading . or an object referred to by .
>
> This problem can be solved in several ways. At the time of standardization, it was not obvious which way would be best

(Note that Stroustup himself has since proposed allowing overloading of `operator.`, as have others, so we may see it in a future version of the language.)